# How do I recover the "text" from the page originating the alert, esp **after** the human user has *clicked* [dismiss] on the page's **alert**?

Tags: javascript, python, alert, dismiss, selenium-firefoxdriver

Basically, when an alert is popped up in javascript, I can `dismiss()` it from python perfectly OK, by calling `selenium.webdriver.common.alert.Alert(browser).dismiss()`.

However, if the "browser user" dismisses the alert by clicking `[OK]` (on screen) with their mouse, then the browser alert gets "Lost in Space" the `body.text` can no longer be accessed from python.

So... How do I recover the "text" from the page originating the alert, esp **after** the human user has *clicked* [dismiss] on the page's **alert**?

Here are the hints and a script to demonstrate the problem...

FYI: The objective of the originating code is it allow the *browser user* intervene *on screen* in testing and manually response to specific alerts.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os,sys,time
import selenium.webdriver
import selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions

print dict(python=sys.version,selenium=selenium.__version__)

path=os.path.join(os.getcwd(),"hello_worlds.html")
url="file:///"+path

open(path,"w").write("""<HTML>
  <HEAD><TITLE>Head Title</TITLE></HEAD>
  <BODY><H1>Hello, worlds!</H1></BODY>
</HTML> """)

browser=selenium.webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get(url)

body=browser.find_element_by_tag_name("body")
print "BODY:",body.text

try:

  for enum,world in enumerate("Mercury Venus Earth Mars Asteroids Jupiter Saturn Uranus Neptune".split()):

    if "Earth" in world: world+=": So do MANUALLY dismiss! {Click [OK] now!!!}"
    else: world+=": AUTO PILOT... please DONT dismiss! {done via selenium.dismiss()!}"

    browser.execute_script('alert("Hello, %s!")'%world)
    if selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.alert_is_present():
      print selenium.webdriver.common.alert.Alert(browser).text

    time.sleep(enum+5)
    if "Earth" not in world: selenium.webdriver.common.alert.Alert(browser).dismiss()

    print "BODY:",body.text

finally:
  browser.quit()
```

Output: (Crash at Earth)

```
{'python': '2.6.6 (r266:84292, Aug 18 2016, 15:13:37) \n[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-17)]', 'selenium': '2.53.2'}
BODY: Hello, worlds!
Hello, Mercury: AUTO PILOT... please DONT dismiss! {done via selenium.dismiss()!}!
BODY: Hello, worlds!
Hello, Venus: AUTO PILOT... please DONT dismiss! {done via selenium.dismiss()!}!
BODY: Hello, worlds!
Hello, Earth: So do MANUALLY dismiss! {Click [OK] now!!!}!
BODY:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./js_alert.py", line 37, in <module>
    print "BODY:",body.text
...
selenium.common.exceptions.UnexpectedAlertPresentException: Alert Text: Hello, Earth: So do MANUALLY dismiss! {Click [OK] now!!!}!
Message: Unexpected modal dialog (text: Hello, Earth: So do MANUALLY dismiss! {Click [OK] now!!!}!) The alert disappeared before it could be closed.
```

The strange thing is that if the *browser user* triggers another alert (on **another** page even!), then a `selenium.dismiss()` will pull `body.text` back from limbo and selenium with *from then* will operate as per (my) expectations.

Any suggestions on how to get the browser back to the `page.body`?  (And escape the alert)

Addendum: Here are similar questions (found with intense searching):

- downloading - [Issues downloading file using Selenium + Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39289271/issues-downloading-file-using-selenium-firefox)
- java alert - [Selenium WebDriver - Unexpected modal dialog Alert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30771067/selenium-webdriver-unexpected-modal-dialog-alert/30773036)
- UnexpectedAlertPresentException - [Webdriver error: "No alert is present" after UnexpectedAlertPresentException is thrown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17576148/webdriver-error-no-alert-is-present-after-unexpectedalertpresentexception-is)
- DesiredCapabilities - [How to handle an Alert with "UnexpectedAlertBehaviour" capability in Selenium?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12913453/how-to-handle-an-alert-with-unexpectedalertbehaviour-capability-in-selenium)
- java&javascript - [org.openqa.selenium.UnhandledAlertException: unexpected alert open](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26772793/org-openqa-selenium-unhandledalertexception-unexpected-alert-open)
- disables exception or DesiredCapabilities - [org.openqa.selenium.UnhandledAlertException: unexpected alert open](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26772793/org-openqa-selenium-unhandledalertexception-unexpected-alert-open)
- non-click suggestion - [When I show a dialog, an exception "UnhandledAlertException: Modal dialog present" is thrown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25200476/when-i-show-a-dialog-an-exception-unhandledalertexception-modal-dialog-presen)
- IE and in the wild - https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium-google-code-issue-archive/issues/4839
- java bug report? https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/webdriver/aNyOfEjMENg
- "still doesn't work." catching exception does not reset the problem - (However almost exactly the same problem) - [how to handle javascript alerts in selenium using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30146259/how-to-handle-javascript-alerts-in-selenium-using-python)
- suggested doing a `driver.findElement(By.id("myAlert"));` but that throws same exception - https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/22482/why-my-alert-is-not-popping-up
- `browser.refresh();` gives `UnexpectedAlertPresentException` so doesn't work. https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/1486
- `browser.switch_to.window(browser.window_handles[0])` then `body.text` gives: `UnexpectedAlertPresentException`
- Similar - [Python webdriver to handle pop up browser windows which is not an alert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17676036/python-webdriver-to-handle-pop-up-browser-windows-which-is-not-an-alert)

Comment: whats wrong with calling dismiss() rather than clicking?

Comment: Basically I have a prompt... "Do you want to continue testing?"  No point getting the script to call accept()/dismiss() when a human is required.

Comment: Ironically, even if I catch the exception in python, AFTER the alert has been manually dismissed or accepted I find the browser is still pointing to the "alert" and another exception is triggered is I try to run `browser.execute_script('alert("Hello, %s!")'%world)` or `selenium.webdriver.common.alert.Alert(browser).dismiss()`.  My conclusion... the alert never disappears and remains in limbo after calls to either `accept()` or `dismiss()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been struggling with this issue off and on for a long time; your comment on your question solved the problem for me:

After both `UnexpectedAlertPresentException` and `NoAlertPresentException` are thrown...

```
browser.execute_script('alert("Clearing out past dialogs.")')
browser.switch_to.alert.accept()
```

As you said in your answer, webdriver is creating a 'dialog' when the alert is present. Closing the alert by hand causes its reference to get lost in limbo, but it's still blocking access to `body.text`. Creating a new alert seems to allow webdriver to clear out that old 'dialog' and (after accepting) grants access to the page again.

Answer (score 0):

No solution yet... I suspect it is a bug in Firefox's webdriver in file *modals.js*

Firefox's web driver captures the alert popup and replaces it with an element named 'dialog' { e.g. `getElementsByTagName('dialog')[0]`}

The problem is that if the tester is human and clicks on either "dismiss" or "accept", then the "onclick" for 'dialog' does not call `fxdriver.modals.clearFlag_`... hence the problem.

https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/javascript/firefox-driver/js/modals.js#LC39

```
fxdriver.modals.isModalPresent = function(callback, timeout) {
    fxdriver.modaltimer = new fxdriver.Timer();
    fxdriver.modaltimer.runWhenTrue(
    function() {
      var modal = fxdriver.modals.find_();
      return modal && modal.document && modal.document.getElementsByTagName('dialog')[0];
    },
    function() { callback(true) },
    timeout,
    function() { callback(false) });
};


fxdriver.modals.acceptAlert = function(driver) {
  var modal = fxdriver.modals.find_();
  var button = fxdriver.modals.findButton_(modal, 'accept');
  button.click();
  fxdriver.modals.clearFlag_(driver);
};
```

https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/javascript/firefox-driver/js/modals.js#LC127

```
fxdriver.modals.setFlag = function(driver, flagValue) {
  driver.modalOpen = flagValue;
};

fxdriver.modals.clearFlag_ = function(driver) {
  fxdriver.modals.setFlag(driver, false);
};
```

Maybe the file_detector selecting local files has a work around...

- http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.file_detector_context

Similar problem:

- [How to debug Firefox alert box closing automatically and being unable to detect the alert in Serenity BDD?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40989047/how-to-debug-firefox-alert-box-closing-automatically-and-being-unable-to-detect)

Bug report:

- https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/4190